# Elementos html se desordenan sin razón aparente

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hola empecé hace poco con el desarrollo pero me he encontrado con problemas muy frustrantes. Estoy usando una plantilla de `bootstrap` para crear un sitio web. Me sucede que el icono de menú queda abajo del logo. Sucedió al agregar mas elementos a la lista del menú y editar los `href` correspondientes.
[image: así]

EL código `html` es este:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top py-3" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
                        <img src="./assets/img/logo/ecco_be.png" width="120" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <button class="boton navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right first-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <div class="animated-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Nosotros</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Servicios</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contactenos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

El `css` es este aunque es un trozo ya que estoy trabajando sobre el de `bootstrap` como estaba en la plantilla.

```
/*Eliminación contorno punteado*/
a, a:active, a:focus, 
button, button:focus, button:active, 
.btn, .btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus, .btn.focus, .btn.focus:active, .btn.active.focus {
    outline: none;
    outline: 0;
}
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
/*Boton icon menu*/
.boton {
   border: 0px;
}
/*Animacion boton icon menu*/
.animated-icon1 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.animated-icon1 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
.animated-icon1 span {
  background: #ffc107;
}
.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 10px;
}
.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 20px;
}
.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -60px;
}
.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg); 
}
```

No comprendo la razón de este error y de algunos otros con los que me he encontrado y seguramente en las lineas de código no este tal vez sea alguna mala práctica que hace que estos errores se presenten. A los elementos del `ul` le agregue 3 `li` y modifiqué los valores de los atributos `href` y `plop` y el icono quedo bajo del logo y aunque di `control z` hasta el cansancio no se arreglo. Agradezco su ayuda acabo de empezar con esto.:) Gracias.

Comment: Utilizar `class="container"`  dentro de otro container es contraproducente. Removiendo eso en el contenedor de `navbar-brand` mejorara el posicionamiento. El logo iria antes o despues del menu?

Comment: antes se supone que el icono estaria posicionado en la derecha como bootstrap lo hace siempre. A y muchas Gracias por responder

Comment: Oye era eso que bueno estaba pensando que era mi computadora, Entonces ¿Deberia siempre tener un solo container por secion de la pagina? Y de antemano gracias no habia podido avazar por ese error. :)

Comment: `class='container`' esta hecho para generar una seccion de pagina con un ancho maximo (sin que ocupe todo el ancho disponible). No deberian en general estar contenidos en otro container https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers

Answer (score 0):

Como dice F.Igor usar un container dentro de otro container no es bueno. Por otro lado observo que despues del div#container que esta dentro del container padre, estas colocando el boton navbar-toggler. Osea, en todo caso creo que podrías solucionar metiendo el boton dentro del container hijo, pero mejor cambiale el nombre a ese container, para que no tengas un container dentro de otro